# How to reload/make my function start again

Tags: javascript

I have been coding with javascript for a little less than a year, but I still consider myself to be pretty new at it. I am trying to make a BlackJack game but I also don't want any duplicate cards to be pulled, so I am trying to see if I can reload the function whenever two cards are the same. This is what I have so far. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
var Ntotal;
var next=parseInt(Math.random()*4)

function Hit(){
    var div=document.getElementById('output');
    document.getElementById('Hit').style.display="none"; 
    document.getElementById('Stay').style.display="none"; 

    var newsum=numbers[cards.indexOf(cards[next])]

    if(cards[next]!=cards[generate] && cards[next]!=cards[pick]){
        div.innerHTM="<img src=' "+cards[next]+" '/> ";
        Ntotal=(total+newsum);
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML="You have a total of "+Ntotal;
    }else{
        Hit.reload(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can shuffle the cards before selecting them from index 0 https://www.frankmitchell.org/2015/01/fisher-yates/

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the page:

`window.location.reload()`

Or you can define a function to clear output.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try it!